# Нужен ли мне DI-контейнер?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Всем привет, на сайте использую стороннюю библиотеку логирования (monolog, но это не важно).

Перед его использованием, нужно создать объект, задать предварительные настройки через методы, указать файл логов разных уровней и т.д.

Этот объект лога мне нужно использовать в разных скриптах проекта.

Здравый смысл подсказывает, что вряд ли нужно каждый раз перед использованием создавать объект и проводить необходимую церемонию по инициализации.

Использовать Singleton в данном случае не хочется (т.к. возможно, что в какой-то момент мне нужно будет создать отдельный объект - в итоге, где-то объет использует синглетон, где-то обычная инициализация - в целом каша).

Скажу честно, я в теории плохо знаком с Инверсией управления (IoC), и DI-контейнерами. (в процессе изучения).

Подскажите пожалуйста, DI-контейнеры решают подобные задачи как у меня? 
Какие есть популярные и простые DI-контейнеры (не швейцарский нож). Я слышал про Pimple, что скажите про него?

Comment: Никто не знает?

Comment: https://packagist.org/?query=di&tags=di. Когда надоест разруливать зависимости самостоятельно, установите контейнер.